# GTK Signals don't work in C program with GTK3 and Anjuta

Tags: c, signals, configure, gtk3, anjuta

I try to write a C program, which uses GTK3. I can compile it, but the callback functions for the signals of GTK don't work. They contain only such things:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT 
void activateWindow(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    g_print("Event: Activate-Default\n");
}
```

but I don't see any output. I have enhanced the template project of Anjuta 3.12, which uses

```
gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
```

to auto-connect the handlers. The handler names I have set in the Glade3 editor, i.e.

```
<signal name="activate-default" handler="activateWindow" swapped="no"/>
```

within the *.ui file. As configuration I have set "Debug" and changed the configure options to

```
--enable-maintainer-mode 'CFLAGS=-g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wl,--export-dynamic' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wl,--export-dynamic' 'JFLAGS=-g -O0' 'FFLAGS=-g -O0'
```

I could compile the program on the command line, but I would like to understand the configuration of Anjuta.

what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show a minimal compilable program (including `main()` and a Glade file defining the window) that demonstrate the issue? Also, not that it should matter, but note that in the callback function the first argument should have type `GtkWindow *`, not `GtkWidget *`.

Comment: I use the wrong signals. I want a signal which occurs on window-open. I have changed the code to window-state-event and I get the output. The changes in the CFLAGS I can add to the Project properties (I have to click on different levels of the project tree to get more option fields...)

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you may be able to use the `show` signal of `GtkWidget *`. The CFLAGS do not matter.

Comment: Anyway, if you are only using the wrong signal, you may want to close this question as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Comment: Most probably, you're looking for `realize()`, which is called when the widget is realized (exists), but before showing on screen.